# Is it possible to add an aperture ring on Nikon G Lenses?

Tags: lens, nikon, aperture

Many of the more affordable Nikon FX Lenses are G Lenses, without the aperture ring.

One of my Cameras is a Nikon FG manual 35mm SLR from the 80s, which could only support a G Lens at the lowest aperture (f/22 or whatever the Lens offers).

Since I'd like to get a 300mm Zoom and since there are a bunch of Nikon FX G ones on eBay, I wonder if there is a practical way to have an Aperture ring retrofitted, or if I should really just decide to either use a newer camera (N80) or cough up the extra cash for a Non-G lens?

Comment: No. But I have to assume that you've only looked at the 28-300, which was only ever available as a G lens (as an all-in-one for the more affordable FX models). You can get an AF 70-300 D (screw drive with aperture ring) for around $200 (or less, depending on condition). No, it's not an all-in-one, but you can't argue with the price.

Comment: @user28116 Thanks for the tip! What do you mean by "all-on-one"? That it doesn't contain an AF Motor in the Lens?

Comment: "all-in-one" is a reference to a very large focal length range, such as the 28-300mm. I call them "all-in-none" because you wind up getting a lens with too many compromises in optical quality just to prevent having to change a lens on that interchangeable lens camera you just bought.

Comment: I just have to mention it because you asked about the AF motor: since the FG is full manual (including manual focus) that means the AF motor and things like VR simply don't matter because they won't work on that camera.

Comment: With most of the N80s listed on eBay right now being under $50, the number of lenses you'd gain access to makes that route's almost a no-brainer.

Comment: @Blrfl I actually own an N80 and you're right, it should be a no-brainer. I just like the way the FG looks and feels though, which is why I love using it. Silly, but well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nikon G Lenses use a mechanical aperture control, so I would guess that it *should* be possible modify one to add a aperture ring. Would it be practical? No.

Either go for a newer camera or an older lens model.